# Graph not drawing correctly when within a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, nodes, graphs

I am having a problem getting a graph to come out correctly.

[image: What I want]
    \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{axis}[
title={},
xlabel={$q$},
ylabel={Time /seconds},
xmin=6, xmax=13,
ymin=30, ymax=70,
xtick={6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13},
ytick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80},
legend pos=north east,
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
height=8cm,
]

\addplot[color=blue] table [x=q6, y=ms6, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=blue] table [x=q7, y=ms7, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=blue] table [x=q8, y=ms8, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=blue] table [x=q9, y=ms9, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=blue] table [x=q10, y=ms10, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=blue] table [x=q11, y=ms11, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=blue] table [x=q12, y=ms12, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=blue] table [x=q13, y=ms13, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\legend{Makespan}

\addplot[color=red] table [x=q6, y=mft6, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=red] table [x=q7, y=mft7, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=red] table [x=q8, y=mft8, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=red] table [x=q9, y=mft9, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=red] table [x=q10, y=mft10, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=red] table [x=q11, y=mft11, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=red] table [x=q12, y=mft12, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=red] table [x=q13, y=mft13, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addlegendentry{Mean Flow Time}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture
```

This gives me the nice graph above.

However, when the graph is made as a node, I get a messed-up graph.
How do I get the graph to come out as in the first picture?

```
\begin{figure*}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[framed, rounded corners]

\node[](6x6_graph)
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={},
    xlabel={$q$},
    ylabel={Time /seconds},
    xmin=6, xmax=13,
    ymin=30, ymax=70,
    xtick={6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13},
    ytick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80},
    legend pos=north east,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    height=8cm,
]

\addplot[color=blue] table [x=q6, y=ms6, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=blue] table [x=q7, y=ms7, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=blue] table [x=q8, y=ms8, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=blue] table [x=q9, y=ms9, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=blue] table [x=q10, y=ms10, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=blue] table [x=q11, y=ms11, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=blue] table [x=q12, y=ms12, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=blue] table [x=q13, y=ms13, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\legend{Makespan}

\addplot[color=red] table [x=q6, y=mft6, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=red] table [x=q7, y=mft7, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=red] table [x=q8, y=mft8, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=red] table [x=q9, y=mft9, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=red] table [x=q10, y=mft10, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=red] table [x=q11, y=mft11, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=red] table [x=q12, y=mft12, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addplot[color=red] table [x=q13, y=mft13, col sep = comma] {6x6_2.csv};
\addlegendentry{Mean Flow Time}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure*}
```

[image: What I don't want.]

Comment: Probably, I didn't realise that \begin{tikzpicture}[framed, rounded corners] at the top-level would do that to all lines within. I'll be honest and admit I only thought it affected the border around the whole picture. \node[right = of 6x6_JSSP.east, anchor=west, rounded corners=0pt](6x6_graph) fixes it.

Comment: That would be your first fake relaxation :) Seriously don't nest them you will get all kinds of strange stuff. Instead change the axis line style.

Comment: First of all, why you want to put it inside a node? Are you planning to arrange different plots side by side or like that? If that is the case use `groupplots` from `pgfplots`. I think this is a XY problem.

Comment: Well I'm arranging this graph and several external figures beside each other. It's working quite well.